# tgt.querytables + webclass

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("CP")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("00")

Dim url As String
Dim symbol As String

symbol = src.Range("C4").Value
url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & symbol & "&p=d"

On Error Resume Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & url, _
    Destination:=tgt.Range("A2"))

    .WebTables = "1"
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "1"
    .WebClass = "snapshot-table2-table"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "An error occurred while retrieving data from the web page."
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

At first, just extracting the full page works, but when I try to specify the table I want to extract by adding the web class - it no longer works!

I tried changing to div element, to td - even try other ids or names.

Answer (score 0):

You must look into the html code and count which table tag the one is you want. In your case it is table tag number 10. Because the index of the first table is 0 you have to use 9 for the 10th table. `WebClass` doesn't exist. You define the needed table only over its index.

```
Sub FinvizTable()

  Dim url As String
  Dim symbol As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim src As Worksheet
  Dim tgt As Worksheet
  
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set src = wb.Sheets("CP")
  Set tgt = wb.Sheets("00")
  symbol = src.Range("C4").Value
  url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & symbol & "&p=d"
  
  With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=tgt.Range("A2"))
      .WebTables = "9"
      .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
      .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
      .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

**Attention:**
With that code you add a new query to the workbook. So only use it once!

To refresh the data you have to refresh the query. Excel named it by a default name. In my german version it is the word `Verbindung`. You must check how it is named in your Excel version. This is the code to refresh the data in the sheet:

```
Sub refresh()
  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Verbindung").refresh
End Sub
```